# Disable UTC for allDay events' start and end moment in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I was wondering if there is a way to have the `start` and `end` moments in the `select (callback)` method be initialised and displayed as the machine's local timezone instead of UTC.

I understand that FullCalendar wants all-day events to be displayed as 12:00am to 12:00am regardless of the timezone (hence why it is always `UTC` by default, display and when its called back), but since I'm using the calendar to schedule time sensitive events, I would like it to use the local timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out a workaround to how full calendar handles all day events by using a nuance of momentjs.

If a `string` is given to `moment(string)` without specifying a timezone, it automatically creates a date in local time.

All I had to do was:

```
start = moment(start.format());
end = moment(end.format());
```